# R言語でcsv形式のデータを元にヒストグラムを描画したい

Tags: r

2つのcsv形式のデータを用いて、R言語でヒストグラムを描画したいのですが、「'x' は数値でなければなりません 」というエラーが出てしまいます。

```
x <- read.csv("Hist1.csv")
y <- read.csv("Hist2.csv")

hist(x, col = "#ff00ff40", border = "#ff00ff", breaks = "Scott")
hist(y, col = "#0000ff40", border = "#0000ff", breaks = "Scott", add = TRUE)
```

以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
 以下にエラー hist.default(x, col = "#ff00ff40", border = "#ff00ff", breaks = "Scott") : 
'x' は数値でなければなりません 
 Calls: hist -> hist.default
 実行が停止されました
```

csvファイルのフォーマット

```
A
1123124
1123131
1123256
1123381
1123506
1123631
1123756
1123881
1124006
1124131
1124256
1124381
1124506
1124631
1124756
1124881
1125006
1125131
1125256
```

Comment: どのような図が表示されることを求めていますか？`hist()`には数値ベクトルしかわたせないので、`hist(x[,1])`などとすると、xの1列目のヒストグラムを描画することはできます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 3100様
> >     ありがとうございます。
> >     以下のように書き換えることで、グラフの出力に成功しました。

```
x <- read.csv("Hist1.csv")
y <- read.csv("Hist2.csv")
hist(x[,1], col = "#ff00ff40", border = "#ff00ff", breaks = 10)
hist(y[,1], col = "#0000ff40", border = "#0000ff", breaks = 10, add = TRUE)
```

[image: ヒストグラム]

Comment: 例えば複数の列を描画したい場合、http://bio-info.biz/tips/r_histogram.html を参考にされると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！たいへん参考になります！！